# SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument. How to bypass it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code

```
print("pay as on ",date1 ,month1 ,year1 ,sep='-'"is : " ,pay_matrix[cell +2][level + 1])
```

I have tried everything I cannot bypass it. It works when I remove sep='-' but I need it.

Comment: Try moving `sep='-'` to the end: `print("pay as on ", date1, month1, year1, "is : ", pay_matrix[cell +2][level + 1], sep='-')`

Comment: You should bring `sep='-'` argument to the end of the `print` since it is an optional argument `print("pay as on ",date1 ,month1 ,year1 ,"is : " ,pay_matrix[cell +2][level + 1], sep='-')`

Comment: What do you not understand from the error message?  You have a positional argument after a keyword argument.  You can't do that -- keyword arguments have to come last.  Where are you stuck on this?

Comment: When I add sep='-' to the end then the output is 'pay as on -1-7-1990-is : -43600' but I want my output to be 'pay as on 1-7-1990 is : 43600'

Comment: @Prune Yes I know that but it doesn't give me the desired output.

Comment: Well, then, you have a *two*  fatal problems.  Please delete this question and post the functional problem separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function to template it.

```
print("pay as on {}-{}-{}, is : {}".format(date1 ,month1 ,year1, pay_matrix[cell +2][level + 1]))
```